# How can R136c be so large?

Tags: astrophysics

I have read the other question (How can a Population III star be so massive)... but it does not answer my question.

R136c Is a Wolfe-Rayet star.  It is 230 the mass of our sun.

My question is this: This star is well passed the Eddington Limit (though if it is a hypothetical metal free star it could be within the Eddington Limit).

1. Why doesn't the radiant pressure blow the extra mass off it?  (Is this only for Pop 1 stars)
2. When it was at around 130 solar masses, why didn't its heat evaporate the material accreting onto it?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you might try the Astronomy exchange.